# Opencv opening an image or window launches Python at 99% CPU utilization

Tags: python, macos, opencv, freeze

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("sample1.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

cv2.imshow("sample1.png", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run the above code on VSCode, I'm expecting a window to pop up to preview the image I have locally inside the script directory I made.

However, Python launches instead, with no window pop up, and just freezes the application. I am have to force quit the application, which from the Activity Monitor on Mac OS (Big Sur 11.1), shows it being 99% CPU utilized.

The same issue arises when I try to generate a simple window; the same Python application with the rocket icon opens and freezes.

Interestingly, if I run the code in IDLE, the preview and window pop-ups open normally.

Is this normal?

Comment: I have a same issue with Big Sur 11.2, python 3.9.1. Any luck so far?

Comment: The issue is with the version of opencv. I resolved my issue by going back one version at a time until it worked. I was using opencv-contrib-python 4.5.1.48. You can also check a discussion [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/238563/imshow-no-window-on-mac-big-sur-with-python)

Comment: Thanks Vahid! I haven't checked your answer, but it makes sense that certain versions of opencv are not working with Big Sur. For example, I was having issues with pyinstaller with Big Sur until the developers finally updated it. 

In the meantime, I will be using my windows pc to construct my code, but I'll downgrade my opencv version for the mac OS when I can. Thank you once again!